# solr autosuggest to stop/filter suggesting the phrase that ends with stopwords

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrcloud

Solr Version 4.7+

Do we have any analyzer or filter or any plugin in solr to stop suggesting the phrase that ends with stopwords?

For ex:
If the suggestion are as below for query http://localhost.com/solr/suggest?q=jazz+a

```
 "suggestion": [  
   "jazz and",  
   "jazz at",  
   "jazz at lincoln",  
   "jazz at lincoln center",  
   "jazz artists",  
   "jazz and classic"  
 ]
```

Is there any config or solution to remove only "***jazz at***" and "***jazz and***" phrases so that the final suggestion response looks more sensible!

```
 "suggestion": [  
   "jazz at lincoln",  
   "jazz at lincoln center",  
   "jazz artists",  
   "jazz and classic"  
 ]
```

Google does this intelligently :)

I have tested with `StopFilterFactory` and `SuggestStopFilter` both of which do not have this feature.

Do I have to come up with a custom plugin to do this in solr?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No not yet, i have tabled this for future development, do you have any info to share on this?